# Can we add home partition by adding an additional hard disk?

Tags: partition, hard-disk, home

I have installed CentOS 6 and I have configured it as a mail server. All user data is stored in the `/home` directory now, but it is running out of space. By adding extra hard drive can I increase the capacity of `/home`?

Comment: That depends on the type of filesystem /home is on. You may have to *move* the data as outlined in one answer. You may be able to *extend* /home. What is the fs type of /home? Are you using LVM?

Answer (score 5):

If you can increase the capacity depends on whether you have LVM installed or not and whether your filesystem supports growing (ext{2,3,4}, btrfs, reiserfs, xfsm, and maybe some others, do)

If you do have LVM you can add the new disc add it to the current `/home` (or if that is not a separate partition `/`) using `vgextend` and `lvextend`.

If you don't have LVM, you can either bring all of `/home` to a partition on the new drive by moving the directories over to the root of the filesystem there and mounting the partition on `/home`.¹ Or, you can decide to split the home directories, by mounting the new partition on `/home2`, moving some homedirectories from `/home` to `/home2` and updating their `/etc/passwd` entries. You should briefly shut down at least the mailaccessing program (`imapd`, `popd`) when you move around individual home directories.

Make sure you have an up-to-date backup before you start doing any of this, especially when playing with LVM.

¹ <sub>This is easy but not extending the home directory, if the new disc is smaller than your current `/home` usage, that would actually decrease the amount of space on `/home`</sub>

Comment: `xfs` allows extending too.

Comment: @bdowning Thanks update the list. It is been a while since I used xfs (on SGI machines, never under Linux)

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can add a separate home partition.

Add the new harddisk, partition it (using fdisk or gdisk), format it (i.e., create a fs using mkfs), move the files under /home to the new fs and edit fstab accordingly so that the system mounts the new fs on top of /home.

If you are using SELinux, you may have issues logging in because of extended attributes not being properly copied to the new filesystem.  There are means of preserving the extended attributes while copying the files, but I found that the better (actually simpler) way of doing this is by restoring them after copying the files.  In order to achieve this, after copying and before logging with any regular user (which files reside in the /home), login as root and execute `restorecon -R -v /home`.

Follows a highlevel step by step:

```
- Add the new harddisk to the system;
- run fdisk (or gdisk) to partition it;
- run mkfs (e.g. "mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdXn" where sdXn is the device referring partition you just created with fdisk);
- mount the new fs under a temporary directory so that you can still see your current /home directory;
- copy the files from your /home to the new fs using "cp -a", "rsync" or your preferred method;
- unmount the new fs;
- add an entry for the new fs in fstab (mine, for instance is: "LABEL=fc20.home /home ext4 defaults,auto_da_alloc,noatime 1 2"
  (notice that I use LABELs for referring to the devices, which you can set with -L with mkfs.ext4 or tune2fs, but of course you can use `/dev/sdXn` instead)
- Mount the new filesystem with "mount -a";
- Before logging with any regular user execute "restorecon -R -v /home"
- after making sure everything is working fine (including after reboot), you should be good to -- temporarily unmount the new /home first -- remove the old files from the original `/home` to free up space in the `/` filesystem.
```

That should be it.  Good luck.

Comment: Using labels as Marcelo does is a safer way than referring to /dev/foo, labels don't change, should you rearrange your hd-cables.
Consider using RAID disks for your /home and do backups.